# Cursor jump to last line when evaluating buffer in ESS

Tags: r, emacs, ess

When I evaluate R code in a buffer using ESS in emacs (v24.3) by either `C-c C-b` or `ess-eval-buffer` the cursor in the buffer jumps to the last line.  How do I keep the cursor on the line I was initially working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the ESS Manual in greater detail revealed `C-c C-l` to be the solution. `ess-eval-buffer` appears to be obsolete as well.

Link: ftp://ftp.stat.math.ethz.ch/ESS/ESS_html-o/ess_7.html#SEC53